# How to List.Remove

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a UDT, let's say:

```
struct myudt{
    public string key; //unique for each item
    public ... // whatever
}
```

and a list:

```
List<myudt> myList;
```

which is the propper/better/faster way to remove an item?

```
void Remove1(string name){
    int i = myList.IndexOf(x => x.key == name);
    myList.RemoveAt(i);
}

void Remove2(string name){
    myudt i = myList.Find(x => x.key == name);
    myList.Remove(i);
}
```

Are there more ways to achive this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you wanting to remove items from a `List<T>` in the first place? Are you familiar with computer-science's fundamental data-structures? If so, then you'll understand why `List<T>` is a very poor choice to store mutable data that requires random (arbitrary) element removal.

Comment: @meysamasadi **YES IT DOES MATTER!** - algorithmic time-complexity is the difference between a program taking a year to do something vs. taking half a millisecond. `List<T>.RemoveAt(Int32)` has `O(n)` complexity, while `Remove(T)` requires at least `2n` (while this is still on the order of `O(n)` it's a noticeable difference).

Comment: I advise you to avoid using the term "UDT" when referring to OOP application program code (especially in Java, C#, C++, etc) because **everything** that isn't a library type is a UDT. The term "UDT" is generally reserved for just user-defined types in database systems where user-defined types are a relative rarity.

Comment: Also, you should read this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/

Comment: @Dai: Your advise is not to use List and nor UDTs. But what would you use instead? If you have a type that only as two or three primitives and no code or events, even a class would be overkill. And using an Array would be so as well when it comes to removing an element in the middle. Any constructive suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @M.Enke I never said "not to use UDTs". I said you shouldn't use _the term_ "UDT" because it's largely meaningless in OOP languages.

Comment: @M.Enke If I have a small number of values I'd likely use a `ValueTuple`. I strongly disagree with your assertion that "a class is overkill" -  I think you do not yet understand how .NET's type system works. (Also don't forget `record` types in C# 9.0 - which are still classes under-the-hood).

Comment: @M.Enke Please answer my question where I ask you what your level of familiarity is with fundamental data structures in computer-science. Do you know what a hashtable, linked-list, binary heap, or binary tree is? I'm asking, because all of those data-structures present viable alternatives to a `List<T>` and array (`T[]`) for performant insertion/deletions in the middle of ordered data.

Answer (score 0):

- Your `Remove1` method requires `O(n)` time to lookup in `IndexOf` and `O(n)` time to perform the removal (because every element inside the internal `T[]` array needs to be relocated).
- Your `Remove2` method requires `O(n)` time to lookup in `Find`, then *another* `O(n)` time inside `Remove` to find the index of the first matching item, and then *another* `O(n)` time to relocate the internal array elements.
- So `Remove1` will be ~50% faster than `Remove2` in the average case (`3n` vs `2n`).
- Also, because you're using a `struct` with [the *slow* default value equality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/) your program will be even slower than it needs to be *even if* you need to use `List<T>.Remove`.

---

However both methods are still suboptimal. If you need to store an arbitrary collection of items such that elements will be added and removed and there is no natural or inherent *ordering* of the elements to benefit any other computation then you should use a `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` depending on your application.

As your `myudt` type has a key value, I think using a `Dictionary<String,myudt>` is appropriate - but you need to ensure your `key` property is immutable - and you should use a `class` not a `struct`:

```
class MyType {
    public MyType( String key ) {
        this.Key = key ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
    }
    public String Key { get; } // <-- This is an immutable property
}

static class DictionaryExtensions {

    public static void Add( this Dictionary<String,MyType> dict, MyType t )
    {
        dict.Add( t.Key, t );
    }

    public static void Remove( this Dictionary<String,MyType> dict, MyType t )
    {
        dict.Remove( t.Key );
    }
}

// This program below will run lightning fast as all individual operations have O(1) time complexity:

Dictionary<String,MyType> dict = new Dictionary<String,MyType>();

for( Int32 i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {
    
    MyType t = new MyType( key: i.ToString() );
    dict.Add( t );
}

for( Int32 i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {
    
    String key = i.ToString();
    dict.Remove( key );
}
```